# Singleton *Singleton::obj = 0; What does that line do in Singleton pattern implementation?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, singleton

This code works fine as an implementation of Singleton pattern.

I want to understand `Singleton *Singleton::obj = 0;`.

What is that doing and why is that important?
Please explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Singleton
{
    private:
        static Singleton *obj;
        Singleton() 
        {
            obj = NULL;
        }

        unsigned int zero = 0;

    public:
        static Singleton * getObject()
        {
            if( obj == NULL )
                obj = new Singleton();
            else
                printf( "\nMemory has already been allocated!\n" );

            return obj;
        }

        void addToZero()
        {
            zero++;
            printf( "\nzero has now become: %d\n", zero );
        }
};

Singleton *Singleton::obj = 0;

int main()
{
    Singleton *p = Singleton::getObject();
    p->addToZero();

    Singleton *p1 = Singleton::getObject();
    p1->addToZero();
}
```

Comment: It's the single instance...

Comment: But we are not using that singleton instance in `int main` for accessing anything. @user1810087

Comment: Actually, you do. `Singleton::getObject();` returns `static Singleton *obj;`, which is initialized in the line you asked extra explanation for.

Comment: Of course you do, twice: `Singleton::getObject();` returns the object `return obj;`.

Comment: It's simply defining the static member variable.